# Django admin static files magically served

Tags: python, django, django-urls, django-staticfiles

I just setup a simple Django website for development, and commented out

`path('admin/', admin.site.urls)`,

with `STATIC_URL = '/static/'` in the settings.py,

When I do `python manage.py runserver 8100` and goto `http://localhost:8100/static/admin/css/nav_sidebar.css`, I see
this static file is magically severed.

What's really going on? I have not setup the static url serving in my urls.py yet? I also do not have another static server like NGINX.

Answer (score 0):

I think the static files are served by e.g. NGINX. They are put to a location where they are accessible once you execute `python manage.py collectstatic` , and then Django does not care about them any more, because they are taken care off by your server. They are outsourced, so to say. Its a different service that handles them. So, the `/static` will be remain accessible regardless of the admin URLs. What you switch on and off with the admin URLs are the pages under `/admin`.

```
http://localhost:8100/admin
```

Will not work anymore, but

```
http://localhost:8100/static/admin
```

will stay untouched.

Comment: So when I run the command "python manage.py runserver 8100", it started another static server?

Comment: There you are using a development server. There is no other service no. However, in production you would serve your site as a wsgi or usgi application and serve the static files via NGINX. In all cases the static files are served.

Comment: Sorry, but this does NOT answer my original question.

Comment: You can try removing  'django.contrib.admin' from the installed apps.

Comment: Please, specify your original question.

Answer (score 0):

So from https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/, when you set `DEBUG=True`, Django will automatically do collectstatics and server the static file thur the URLs for you.

Answer (score 0):

When you do a `python manage.py runserver` you are using the django's inbuilt development server which serves both static files and app logic. So it is an app server + static file server. If you use a specific app server like gunicorn, then you have to use an nginx to server static files and this is what you should do in production.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/settings/#staticfiles-finders

You probably did what I did, go to the settings.py file, find or add STATICFILES_FINDERS = []

Add the following two items:

`django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder`

`django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder`,

python manage.py collectstatic should work with DEBUG=False